# MySQL SELECT query takes a while on a wikipedia local copy

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

I have a local copy of Wikipedia (~30GO for english) stored in a MySQL database.
I have two columns :

1. "title" whitch is the primary key and the title of the article (varchar(238))
2. "body" whitch is the content of the article (mediumtext)

My problem is that for a very simple query (using the primary key) it takes a while (~50ms whitch is too much because I'm creating program that takes info from these articles sequencialy in 10 languages ; 2 articles (for each languages) / sec is too less).

The query is the following :

```
SELECT * FROM wiki_en WHERE title = "Appel" LIMIT 1
```

I don't know why it take so long (usualy, my select query when using index takes ~1ms).

Comment: If it's really a primary key then your query will result in a unique row so you won't need a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: @ Neil : I know, but it was just to be sure to not overload MySQL
@ biziclop : I beleave that Octet is right in english too (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) ; sorry if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
analyze table wiki_en;
```

then run the query again.

Also, using such a "wide" key isn't recommended. Why don't you use a simple integer id field (like 99% of all tables out there)?

Lastly, have you actually defined `title` as `PRIMARY KEY` in your table definition? If not, you'll need to `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...` for that column.

Comment: I use the title as an index so i can find an article with his name despite of his id (I scan each articles and for each I look for the wiki-links for other languages and so I can get this article for each languages). Title is defined as the primary key.